# jQuery $.unique documentation requires correction

Tags: jquery, unique

According to jQuery documentation of $.unique - https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/ it says that $.unique is not used for strings and numbers. It says it removes duplicates and sorts the DOM elements.

But please refer - https://jsfiddle.net/d6v3pemf/ the strings and numbers. The sorting is not happening, but the duplicates have been removed.

```
var a  = [3,5,1,2,8,9,0,3,4,2,5,6,1,8];
var x = $.unique(a);

var b = ["a","r","w","u","a","q","r"];
var y = $.unique(b)

console.log(x);
console.log(y);
```

Is jQuery documentation missing something

Answer (score 0):

`$.unique` sorts the **`DOM`** elements like `div or p` etc. not the strings and integers *but removes duplicates in both the cases*.

You need to use `sort()` to achieve your desired result as

```js
var a  = [3,5,1,2,8,9,0,3,4,2,5,6,1,8];
var x = $.unique(a).sort();

var b = ["a","r","w","u","a","q","r"];
var y = $.unique(b).sort();
alert(x);
alert(y);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```